# How to use correctly Pyflowchart output

Tags: python

I'm trying to use pyflowchart package that print this output on VSC terminal after using the command `python -m pyflowchart 2-4-8.py`:

```
op2=>operation: from netmiko import ConnectHandler
op4=>operation: from getpass import getpass
op6=>operation: from datetime import datetime
op8=>operation: import logging
op10=>operation: import snoop
sub12=>subroutine: logging.basicConfig(filename='script.log', filemode='w', 
level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
op14=>operation: password = getpass()
op16=>operation: Device1 = {'device_type': 'juniper_junos', 'ip': 'x.x.x.x', 'username': 
'user', 'password': password}
op18=>operation: Device2 = {'device_type': 'juniper_junos', 'ip': 'x.x.x.x', 'username': 
'user', 'password': password}
op20=>operation: Device3 = {'device_type': 'juniper_junos', 'ip': 'x.x.x.x', 'username': 
'user', 'password': password}
op22=>operation: route = input('Route to verify: ')
op24=>operation: command = 'show version | match Hostname'
op26=>operation: command1 = f'show route {route} | match "localpref|>"'
op28=>operation: clear_txt = open('Interfaces.txt', 'w')
op30=>operation: Interfaces = open('Interfaces.txt', 'w')
cond33=>condition: for device in (Device1, Device2, Device3)
op126=>operation: net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
op128=>operation: output = net_connect.send_command(command)
op130=>operation: output1 = net_connect.send_command(command1)
op132=>operation: now = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
op134=>operation: head = ('-' * 65)
op136=>operation: dev = output.split()[(- 1)]
sub138=>subroutine: print(f'''{head}
{now} --> ### HOSTNAME: {dev} ###
{head}''', file=Interfaces)
op140=>operation: output1 = output1.replace(',', '').split('\n')
cond143=>condition: for line in output1
op180=>operation: line = line.split()
cond183=>condition: if ('localpref' in line)
op187=>operation: ldata = line[(line.index('localpref') + 1)]
cond192=>condition: if ('via' in line)
op196=>operation: vdata = line[(line.index('via') + 1)][:(- 2)]
op198=>operation: command2 = f'show interface {vdata} descriptions'
op200=>operation: output2 = net_connect.send_command(command2)
op202=>operation: ddata = output2[66:]
op204=>operation: result = f'{now} --> localpref {ldata} --> via {vdata} --> {ddata}'
sub206=>subroutine: print(result, file=Interfaces)
sub216=>subroutine: Interfaces.close()

op2->op4
op4->op6
op6->op8
op8->op10
op10->sub12
sub12->op14
op14->op16
op16->op18
op18->op20
op20->op22
op22->op24
op24->op26
op26->op28
op28->op30
op30->cond33
cond33(yes)->op126
op126->op128
op128->op130
op130->op132
op132->op134
op134->op136
op136->sub138
sub138->op140
op140->cond143
cond143(yes)->op180
op180->cond183
cond183(yes)->op187
op187->cond143
cond183(no)->cond192
op196->op198
op198->op200
op200->op202
op202->op204
op204->sub206
sub206->cond143
cond192(no)->cond143
cond143(no)->cond33
cond33(no)->sub216
```

I tried to read on https://pypi.org/project/pyflowchart/ how to use this output but for me is not clear, I tried to past this on markdown editor, I tried to use https://flowchart.js.org/ and I tried to create a .flowchart file but I can't figure out what to do. So my question is, can someone point me out how can I convert this output in a grafical flowchart?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a stupid question or nobody can point me out? Thanks

Comment: After a lot of researches, I have found this program that do exactly what I'm looking for, Visustin V8 https://www.aivosto.com/visustin.html, I'm using the demo version that have some limitations but it is enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -o flag and specify an output file name. For HTML output:

python -m "pyflowchart 2-4-8.py" -o flowchart.html

You can then open the html to view the graphical flow chart.

Documented on https://pypi.org/project/pyflowchart/ in the quick start section.